# Owin Authentication: SSO token vs ID token

Tags: asp.net, authentication, owin, openid-connect, claims-based-identity

I have implemented sign-in to Microsoft to my ASP.NET web application. Everything works as intended, but I am struggling to comprehend how the sessions work. I am using OWIN middleware and OpenID connect.

1. What is the difference between the SSO-Token and the ID-token? Which
   one keeps me logged in?
2. What happens if I try to access claims ( e.g.
   userClaims?.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.sid)?.Value)
   from an expired ID token?
3. How does !Request.IsAuthenticated realize that the current user is
   Authenticated after the microsoft login? Is this because The Generic
   Identity, is now a Claims Identity, that returns true?
4. If I am logged in, and keep refreshing the site, at what point will
   I be forced to Authenticate again? And what controls this time?

I understand what an ID-token is, and that it carries claims, and how I access and use the claims. I am just confused about how the session works after a user has logged in with their Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no SSO token. The id token represents proof of authentication and some basic user info is included in it. So your web app can get name, email etc.
2. Expiry is based on an auth cookie that the MS libraries issue. This is tied to another token, the refresh token, which represents the session time.
3. The id token has a digital signature that is cryptographically verified. Also your app supplies a client secret to help ensure that tokens can be trusted.
4. The cookie is given an expiry related to the refresh token. When the cookie expires the user has to login again.

**FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING**

I would strongly recommend tracing messages, via a tool such as Fiddler, as in [this blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/24/spa-and-api-final-http-messages/) of mine.

Personally I prefer Single Page Apps, which only use tokens and not cookies. They make OAuth aspects easier to understand and code can be simpler, though there are still plenty of subtleties.